# When I insert a image into MySQL table the result is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, mariadb

What's wrong with this code, I want to insert an image to table, but when I was executed this code the result of image field is `NULL`.

I try with *MySQL Workbench* executing:

```
CREATE TABLE image(keyh int, img blob);
INSERT INTO image VALUES(1, load_file('d:\Picture\cppLogo.png'));
```

Comment: You already checked this? - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

Comment: Possibility: use `load_file('d:/Picture/cppLogo.png')` i.e. change dos backslash to unix forwardslash

Comment: Please note, that the BLOB data type has a maximum of 64K bytes of storage. Advised to use MEDIUMBLOB (max is 16M) or LONGBLOB (4G size) Refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html

Comment: oke bro i i will try to canget type to longblob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you
>   must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the
>   FILE privilege. The file must be readable by all and its size less
>   than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable
>   is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be
>   located in that directory.
>
> If the file does not exist or cannot be read because one of the
>   preceding conditions is not satisfied, the function **returns NULL**.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file

What can you do?

Check which user mysql is running with, and make sure the file is readable by that user. Make sure the security settings allow the file to be read and it is not of greater size than `max_allowed_packet`.

See `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'`.

For me, it looks like the file is on your localhost and you try to **upload** it. This is not possible using `LOAD_FILE()`. The file must be already on the server.

The issue can also be caused by your windows directory seperator character `\` (like [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723126/inserting-image-into-mysql-table-the-result-is-null/41723191?noredirect=1#comment70641174_41723126) said), which is used for escaping instead, switch to unix style `/` then:

```
LOAD_FILE('D:/Picture/cppLogo.png')
```

Or your Image is of greater filesize than a `BLOB` field can hold, like [Balazs Vago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723126/inserting-image-into-mysql-table-the-result-is-null/41723191?noredirect=1#comment70641404_41723126) said.

Comment: Dan, this looks like windows, so assuming the file is on the same PC as MYSQL permissions should not be an issue

Comment: You might be correct. Maybe it's simply because of the directory seperator like you said.

Comment: Fell free to add that as an option to your answer

Comment: @RiggsFolly actually, in some versions of windows, one may need to run under admin. I've seen that happen.

Comment: Yup, you is d'man @Fred-ii- But the MYSQL service normally runs as an admin in my experience. Unless the user is well on the ball

Comment: Yes, when run as a windows service (`SYSTEM` user).

Comment: @RiggsFolly Hard to say and if they are on windows or a \*NIX OS.

Comment: `D:` is a bit of a clue, my old mucker

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, got me there `:p` but you said... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41723126/inserting-image-into-mysql-table-the-result-is-null#comment70641174_41723126

Comment: Yea. Apache and PHP when compiled for windows have a SLASH converter built in. Not so sure about MYSQL though

Comment: Anyway, Dan seems to have it all covered, and the Questioner has gone quiet so I am going to sneek of and look for another question

Comment: i use windows,  but i don't know mysql  like unix os

Answer (score 1):

i was found the correct syntax is following this:

`C:/wamp/binsql5.5.20/data/56VRLRFE.jpg'`

not this

`C:\wamp\binsql5.5.20\data\56VRLRFE.jpg'`

thanks guys for all your Answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Open your MySql Command Line Client and login with root user and type

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
```

this will show you the secure path used by MySql to access the files. something like

```
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

you can either paste files inside this folder or change the "secure_file_priv" variable value to "empty string" so that it can read file from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows the fundamental problem is that MySql, by default, runs as a Windows service under the Network account which means that there are only a few file locations the server can access.  Thus for load_file to work, the file must be placed in a folder on the server which can be read by the service.  There seems to be no documentation on this.  In my investigation the only folder that works with load_file is C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads

Run a query to test the load...

```
select load_file('C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\1.txt') ;
```

Note on windows you have to use either double \ or / to separate the path elements.  This will return NULL on failure, otherwise the contents of the file.

Assume now a table named db.image with columns source and image.  Source is character and image is blob.  The command to load a.jpg into the table would be

```
insert into db.image (source,image) values ('a.jpg',load_file('c:/programdata/mysql/mysql server 8.0/uploads/a.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Store Directly Without folder name for example-

```
create table myimg(id int, image mediumblob);

insert into myimg values(101, load_file("E://xyz.png"));
```